# Describing all the linear transformations satisfying the constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

How to find the linear transformation $T: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ such that the set of all vectors satistfying $4x_1-3x_2+x_3=0$ is

a) Null space of $T$

b) Range of $T$

I'm not able to approach this problem.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things 
about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if 
you write what your thoughts 
are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in 
this and future posts and in what context you have encountered the problem; this will prevent people 
from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers 
at the right level.

Comment: I'd suggest looking up the definition of Null Space and Range in order to fully understand what you're looking for. I'll give you a hint:

$Dim(KerT)+Dim(ImT)=Dim(R^3))$

Answer (score 0):

What is the null space of $\begin{bmatrix}4&-3&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/571614)

Comment: @N.F.Taussig : That was a hint..

Comment: The art of writing a good hint is difficult to master. I'm not sure this is a good one, but ... none of the 7 users who voted in favor of deleting this post in the low quality queue felt like downvoting it. Therefore I am not inclined to do their dirty work for them. Leaving the flag open in case a fellow diamond bearer feels differently. The vote came out 7-1, which is usually clear enough. You should take that as a strong suggestion to improve the post.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : Sir, Thanks for bearing my inability to writing a good hint.. I will keep this in my mind in further answers..